# Why does getCurrentposition using google maps with jquery ui map and jquery mobile cause an error?

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-map

I am trying to  get the current position using the jquery-ui-map (getCurrentPoistion), but iIkeep getting this error:

> Uncaught no such method 'getCurrentPosition' for gmap widget instance

This is my code:

```
var defaultLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(-0.9516469154747268, 30.269393920898438);
$('#map_canvas_dir').gmap({ 'center': defaultLoc, 'zoom':10});
$('#submit').click( function() {
    $('#map_canvas_dir').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(status, pos) {
        if (status === "OK") {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude,
                                                pos.coords.longitude);
            $('#map_canvas_dir').gmap('option', 'center', latLng);
            addNewMarker( latLng, 'green' );            
        }
        else {
            console.log('shit! it failed again');
        }                    
    }, { timeout: 4000, enableHighAccuracy: true } );
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to get the position of? If its the physical location of the user, try looking at navigator.geolocation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_geolocation

Comment: There's no indication in the question that you've followed the documentation and implemented that method. It's not native to jquery-ui-map. http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/Examples#Example_get_user_position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew Leach mentioned, the getCurrentPosition is an extension of the plugin. Most likely you haven't included jquery-ui-map-extensions.js

Comment: Oh yeah, I did realized that as soon as i looked at the documentation. It is now working well, but i have failed to do reverse geocoding ....

Comment: Check out this example. http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-geocoding.html